# Deploy Azure function app with private endpoint results gateway error

Tags: azure-devops, azure-functions, azure-blob-storage, azure-private-link

I am trying to do ZIP deployment of azure function app that has private endpoint enabled. As a part of this , I created azure resources as follow:

- Function app with private endpoint enabled and disabled Allow public access on.
- Storage account with private endpoint enabled, disabled public access and associcate with function app. I make sure private IP is added to Private DNS Zone A record.
- Created VNET with 2 subnets such as InboundSubnet, OutboundSubnet. I associated same inbound subnets while creating azure function app, storage account. For Azure VNET integration outbound traffic , I used OutboundSubnet.

Since inbound traffic for function , storage is cut off with internet access, I published my ZIP to a storage account(Newly created and public enabled) via build(CI) pipeline and fetching the same ZIP file in release pipeline to deploy.

However I am getting below issues:

**The gateway did not receive a response from 'Microsoft.Web' within the specified time period**

**Encountered an error (InternalServerError) from host runtime.**  - From aztivity log

***Update:*** - Ran CLI command from local machine

The command failed with an unexpected error. Here is the traceback:
HTTPSConnectionPool(host='demo-funcapp-test.scm.azurewebsites.net', port=443): **Max retries exceeded with url**: /api/publish?type=zip&async=false (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x05EA4B50>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed'))

**NSG Inbound Rules:**

[image]
App settings of azure function app.

```
[
  {
    "name": "AzureWebJobsStorage",
    "value": "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=oshpocrg8094;AccountKey=STORAGEACCOUNTKEY;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net",
    "slotSetting": false
  },
  {
    "name": "FUNCTIONS_EXTENSION_VERSION",
    "value": "~4",
    "slotSetting": false
  },
  {
    "name": "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME",
    "value": "dotnet",
    "slotSetting": false
  },
  {
    "name": "WEBSITE_CONTENTAZUREFILECONNECTIONSTRING",
    "value": "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=oshpocrg8094;AccountKey=STORAGEACCOUNTKEY;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net",
    "slotSetting": false
  },
  {
    "name": "WEBSITE_CONTENTOVERVNET",
    "value": "1",
    "slotSetting": false
  },
  {
    "name": "WEBSITE_CONTENTSHARE",
    "value": "test-pvent-func",
    "slotSetting": false
  },
  {
    "name": "WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE",
    "value": "1",
    "slotSetting": false
  },
  {
    "name": "WEBSITE_TIME_ZONE",
    "value": "UTC",
    "slotSetting": false
  }
]
```

**Release Pipeline:**

```
steps:
- task: AzureCLI@2
  displayName: 'Azure CLI : Deploy file to Function App'
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: 'Visual Studio Enterprise Subscription (44444c7b-1f7a-43a1-a90f-dee45a2f6262)'
    scriptType: ps
    scriptLocation: inlineScript
    inlineScript: |
      az extension add --name webapp
     
     $ZIP_URL = (az storage blob generate-sas --full-uri --permissions r --expiry 2023-12-31T23:59:59Z --account-name publicsgtest -c functionzipfiles -n build.zip | Out-String).Trim()
     
     Write-Host 'ZIP File URL:' $ZIP_URL
     
     az webapp deploy --name demo-funcapp-test --resource-group osh-poc-rg --type zip --src-url $ZIP_URL --async false
```

**Partial release logs:**

```
2023-12-04T15:21:37.5470046Z [command]C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -NoLogo -NoProfile -NonInteractive -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Command ". 'D:\a\_temp\azureclitaskscript1701703229248.ps1'"
2023-12-04T15:21:55.3254967Z WARNING: The installed extension 'webapp' is in preview.
2023-12-04T15:22:04.8371024Z WARNING: 
2023-12-04T15:22:04.8372046Z There are no credentials provided in your command and environment, we will query for account key for your storage account.
2023-12-04T15:22:04.8374096Z It is recommended to provide --connection-string, --account-key or --sas-token in your command as credentials.
2023-12-04T15:22:04.8374775Z 
2023-12-04T15:22:04.8375927Z You also can add `--auth-mode login` in your command to use Azure Active Directory (Azure AD) for authorization if your login account is assigned required RBAC roles.
2023-12-04T15:22:04.8377688Z For more information about RBAC roles in storage, visit https://docs.microsoft.com/azure/storage/common/storage-auth-aad-rbac-cli.
2023-12-04T15:22:04.8378502Z 
2023-12-04T15:22:04.8379753Z In addition, setting the corresponding environment variables can avoid inputting credentials in your command. Please use --help to get more information about environment variable usage.
2023-12-04T15:22:06.1828417Z ZIP File URL: "https://publicsgtest.blob.core.windows.net/functionzipfiles/build.zip?SASTOKENATTACHED"
2023-12-04T15:23:15.3930471Z ERROR: Gateway Timeout({"error":{"code":"GatewayTimeout","message":"The gateway did not receive a response from 'Microsoft.Web' within the specified time period."}})
2023-12-04T15:23:15.7272696Z ##[error]Script failed with exit code: 1
2023-12-04T15:23:15.7438810Z [command]C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /D /S /C ""C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\CLI2\wbin\az.cmd" account clear"
2023-12-04T15:23:17.0799266Z ##[section]Finishing: Azure CLI : Deploy file to Function App
```

Reference link: https://azure.github.io/AppService/2021/03/01/deploying-to-network-secured-sites-2.html

**What am I missing?**

Comment: Hi there, to help isolate the cause of the issue, may I know if you have tried to run the Azure CLI command on your local machine and if the issue is reproducible?

Comment: @AlvinZhao I updated my question with more updates. I tried like you said and now I am getting ```HTTPSConnectionPool``` issue. I had disabled public access to SCM for security purposes , is that causing issue?

Comment: So, may I assume you have disabled public access to your `scm` (advanced tool site) and enabled private endpoint for `demo-funcapp-test` and would use the zip file from `publicsgtest` with SAS-token URL for deployment? I am not sure if the SAS-token URL is accessible through PE. For this, would you also test to enable PE for this storage account? The failure on local machine can rule out the cause by pipeline; however, would you consider using self-hosted VM agent within the PE for the deployment pipeline? Hope the experts from App Services may share more insights.

Comment: @AlvinZhao
Yes, I disabled public access for SCM as well. Yes I use ZIP file from ```publicsgtest``` with SAStoken url for deployment.  I already using PE for storage account that required for azure function but i store ZIP file in another storage account with public access. I can consider VM as 2nd option as we dont want to create multiple resources in azure.
I shared reference link in my question which I am following that,

Comment: Would you consider deploying to slot first and then swap the slots? The deployment to slot should be via public network so it is not restricted by PE and we don't need to create VM to set up self-hosted agent with PE in the vnet.

Comment: @AlvinZhao currently there is no deployment slots enabled, but I can give a try.

Comment: Hi there, Would you minding [accepting it as answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235), since you've added useful workaround here? Thx for the sharing. Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure, what is the exact issue, this is log I got from support team.

**Error:** The gateway did not receive a response from `Microsoft.Web` within the specified time period

**Root cause of Error:**:
Your application process failed to start up in this time frame because the process could not access the storage account which hosted your application content from the subnet with which the application was integrated using regional virtual network integration. This can most likely occur due to the network configurations on the subnet or the firewall rules of the storage account. Please disconnect and re-connect the regional virtual network integration first and then check if the application can start up. If the problem still exists, you need to check the network settings to allow SMB file access from the subnet to the storage account.

**Fix:**
As a workaround, I did following steps that makes  it working for me.

1. Created azure function app, storage account as public access and deployed using Azure Devops pipeline which is success. Here I deploy with only 1 Azure function say `Function1` which I can see in azure portal.
2. Disabled public access for function app , storage and created VNET, Private endpoints, azure private dns zone etc., required resources to make it fully private access.
3. Created another function http trigger say `Function2` in VS code and deployed through devops build and release pipelines. I can see `Function2` in azure portal.

**Release Pipeline YAML code:**

[image]

[image]

I am still trying my luck to do directly with private endpoints.

Answer (score 0):

Which build agent are you using? Consider adding [AzureDevOps](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/devops/azure-devops-service-tag-released/) service tag in your NSG rules if you try deploying from the ms-hosted build agent because it has no access to your private resources.  Or you may create VM and register a new build agent in your private net.

Comment: I am using ```Azure Pipelines``` MS hosted.  Please refer my question for all inbound NSG rules.